# Bitbucket maven cache and the clean phase

Tags: maven, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm newish to DevOps and new to Maven and I have a question regarding the Bitbucket maven cache.

Our current build pipeline is set to use a maven cache, and the actual build command is `./mvnw clean install`. In my head this doesn't make any sense to me because anything that was cached by the pipeline in the last build, will be 'cleaned' in the next build by the `clean` phase.
Does that sound right, or am I missing something?

Thank you for the help.

Scott

Comment: Does your CI engine allow to carry files from build to build?  If yes, this is what you should do with `~/.m2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn clean` will only remove build artifacts from your project's folders.

BitBucket by default caches Maven's `~/.m2` folder where it downloads all the dependencies used in your build. Nothing in there is getting wiped with `clean`.

https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/mvn-clean-install-a-short-guide-to-maven

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/#Pre-defined-caches